# Python - How to get print statement to print max number of times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the code below and it prints what I need but I need the code to execute twice based on the def function. I'm sure this would be simple but I can't figure this out for the life of me

```
def countdownWhile(n, max_repeat):
    # display countdown from n to 1
    while n > 0:
        print (n)
        n = n-1
        if n == 0:

            print('blast off')
```

I got the following output on running the code:

```
>>> countdownWhile(5,2)
5
4
3
2
1
blast off
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def countdownWhile(n, max_repeat):
    for i in range(max_repeat):
        for x in range(n,0,-1):
            print (x)
    print('blast off')
```

Run

```
In [6]: countdownWhile(5,2)
5
4
3
2
1
5
4
3
2
1
blast off
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a for loop

```
for i in range(max_repeat):

    n2=n

    while n2 > 0:

        print (n2)

        n2 = n2-1

        if n2 == 0:

            print('blast off')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop for the max_repeat parameter too.

```
def countdownWhile(n, max_repeat):
    # display countdown from n to 1
    while max_repeat > 0:
         while n > 0:
             print (n)
             n = n-1
             if n == 0:
                 print('blast off')
         max_repeat -= 1
```

This would print the countdown `max_repeat` number of times.